# What does Bucket mean?

Tags: terminology

I found in legacy code a class which name is BucketService.

Because english is not my native language I was trying to translate that, but it doesn't make sense.

I found few termins like bucket sorting and so on, but I still don't get it. Actually this word is used quite frequently in programming

I would be helpfull for some simple explanation of that word

Comment: never judge the class by its name. What API does it expose? what state does it contain? how is it used / invoked / instantiated? without knowing that, the only correct answer to question like yours seems to be [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29 "'unask the question'")

Comment: Particularly with nondescript name like "BucketService" - it sounds like "UtilityManager" or "ThingDoer". With a vague name like that, your only option is to look at the code. Unfortunately, classes with names _that_ vague generally do a little bit of everything (or a lot of everything, if you're unlucky).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A [bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket) in English is a device for holding water.

When used in software, it normally means a data type that groups objects together.

The term is used often when discussing [hashing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_algorithm), where different items that have the same hash code (hash collision) go into the same "bucket". Meaning, the objects are grouped by the hash.

> In general, a hashing function may map several different keys to the same index. Therefore, each slot of a hash table is associated with (implicitly or explicitly) a set of records, rather than a single record. For this reason, each slot of a hash table is often called a bucket, and hash values are also called bucket indices.

Informally, I have seen the term used with dictionaries whose value (not key) is a collection of items.

---

Wikipedia has a page dedicated to the term as used in computing - [Bucket (Computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_%28computing%29):

> In computing, the term bucket can have several meanings. It is used both as a live metaphor, and as a generally accepted technical term in some specialised areas. A bucket is most commonly a type of data buffer or a type of document in which data is divided into regions.

Comment: +1 you beat me to it!  I would like to add that the purpose of the hash algorithm sorting elements into buckets allows for quicker retrieval and sorting of large collections.  If I want to search 20 items for a specific item, then the inefficient way would be to search one at a time by ID.  A better way would be for a collection to keep items with the same hash into a **bucket**, so only a few items need to be searched in the bucket rather than the whole list.

Comment: @maple_shaft - Good point about the use of buckets in hashing. I didn't think it was relevant to the question though :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a reference to 'bit bucket'.  That's where the bits that get shifted off a byte go on left and right bit shifts.